# Angular 2 application cache issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am a beginner in Angular 2 and working on small projects.
I am working on Angular (7.2.6)
I have added a simple button in `app.component.html`. 
Given a click even '`onButtonClick`' and written the event in app.component.ts 
I have added a simple alert in the `onButtonClick` event.

Everything worked fine, i got the alert.

After that, I deleted the alert and again ran the project. Surprisingly I am still getting the alert. 
I restarted the machine and alert stopped coming :)
Am I missing something in my learning of Angular ?

Comment: your code may have been _cached_ to a previous version

Comment: try to clear cache after editing code.

Comment: How to prevent caching ? 
I am facing this issue randomly. 
Sometimes I am adding HTML but its not reflecting. 
I have to add some text in HTML so that i can see my entire changed HTML. 

Its weird !

Answer (score 0):

singe Angular 2 runs on NodeJs. you can start by clearing the Nodejs cache with these commands

```
npm cache clean 
npm cache clear
```

then, you can clear the angular template cache through the angular template compiler

```
import { RuntimeCompiler} from @angular/compiler

constructor(
   private _rc: RuntimeCompiler
){}

clearCache(){
  this._rc.clearCache();
}
```

i hope this works for you.

Comment: If i deploy my Angular application for the users, will it behave in same manner ? 
Will the users see my updated changes ? 
Otherwise my company will kick me off .. :(

Comment: yea.. they will see the updated changes, since you are deploying the final build

Comment: remember to add [ RuntimeCompiler ] to your providers array

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome, then just open `Developer Tools` by clicking `F12` and by default at the `Network` tab, `Disable Cache` should be checked.

OR

use HotKey in Google Chrome `Ctrl+Shft+R`.